# Why sometimes second test executes after first one with Angular Jasmine Unit Testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am learning how to Angular Test and something strange happens to me. Thing is, WITH THE SAME EXACT CODE, when I do `ng test` sometimes the substract IT block is executed before the add IT block, when this one is supposed to be executed the first (and sometimes it actually does):

This is the spec code:

```
import { CalculatorService } from './calculator.service';
describe ('calculatorService',()=>{

    let calculator:CalculatorService;
    let loggerSpy:any;

    beforeEach(()=>{

        console.log ("calling the beforeEach");

        loggerSpy=jasmine.createSpyObj('LoggerServiceSpy', ['log']);

        calculator= new CalculatorService(loggerSpy);

    });


    it('should add two numbers', ()=>{


        let result=calculator.add(2,2);

        console.log ("add test");

        expect(result).toBe(4);
        expect(loggerSpy.log).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it('should substract two numbers', ()=>{




        let result=calculator.subtract(2,2);

        console.log ("substract test");

        expect(result).toBe(0, "unexpected substracion result");
        expect(loggerSpy.log).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

        
    });

});
```

And this what I obtain sometimes:

[image]

Other times I just kill terminal (**integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code, it this helps you**), execute `ng test` again, and normal flow is done... What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**EDIT:** I add the calculator and logger services code in case it helps (also I don´t know why `this.logger.log` test is not outputed when I do the `ng test` but I guess that is another question

**calculator-service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {LoggerService} from './logger.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CalculatorService {


  constructor(private logger: LoggerService) {

  }

  add(n1: number, n2:number) {
    this.logger.log("Addition operation called");

    return n1 + n2;
  }

  subtract(n1: number, n2:number) {
    this.logger.log("Subtraction operation called");
    return n1 - n2;
  }


}
```

**logger-service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoggerService {

  log(message:string) {
    console.log(message);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that Jasmine executes tests in a random order by default. This can be changed by setting `random: false` in your `karma.conf` file under the `jasmine` property as shown [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) in the README.

This default behavior of running your unit tests randomly is actually a good thing, however. A general principle of writing good unit tests is to write them in such a way as they are fully self-contained -- meaning, each test has everything it needs to execute by itself. If your tests have to run in a specific order in order to pass, it generally means the tests depend on each other, and this is considered bad practice.

If you *have* to run your tests in a specific order for some reason though, you can certainly do so.